# I'm trying to open side panels with overlay and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify

I'm trying to code my own Shopify theme and in that, I want to create different side panels (all coming in from the right) when someone clicks the panel link. I managed to get this to work with one panel and a script I found here on Stackoverflow (sorry I'm a complete newbie), but now I can't open different panels. Each link opens them all (obvious) but couldn't manage to trigger by the ID (my guess how to solve it) rather than the classes.

I would also like the overlay to close the panels. I only manage this by adding the toggle button into each panel.

My sidepanel script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  function toggleSidebar() {
    $(".sidepanel-toggle").toggleClass("active");
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("active");
    $(".sidepanel").toggleClass("active");
    $("body").toggleClass("activeoverlay");
  }

  $(".sidepanel-toggle").on("click tap", function() {
    toggleSidebar();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      toggleSidebar();
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

And the HTML for handling the panels

```
  <a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle">meta data</a>
  
  <aside id="extra_prod_meta" class="sidepanel">
    meta data
  </aside>

  <a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle">Brand</a>

  <aside id="extra_prod_brand" class="sidepanel">
    meta data
  </aside>
```

Comment: Because you are targeting the ```class```, which they both have in your example.
Add a ```data-attribute``` to the side panel or target the ```id```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$body = $('body');

$('a.sidepanel-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let _this = $(this),
      tg = _this.data('panel');
  
  addActivePanel(tg,_this);

});

$('.close, .overlay').on('click', function(){
    removeActivePanel();
});

function removeActivePanel(){
    
  $body.removeClass('activeoverlay');
  $('a.sidepanel-toggle, aside').removeClass('active');
  
}

function addActivePanel(panel,btn) {
    
  $body.addClass('activeoverlay');
  
  $('#'+panel).addClass('active');
  btn.addClass('active');
      
}
```

```css
aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: right .3s ease;
}

aside.active {
  right: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.activeoverlay .overlay {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.close {
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle" data-panel="extra_prod_meta">meta data</a>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <aside id="extra_prod_meta" class="sidepanel">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    meta data extra_prod_meta
  </aside>

  <a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle" data-panel="extra_prod_brand">Brand</a>

  <aside id="extra_prod_brand" class="sidepanel">
    <div class="close">X</div>
    meta data extra_prod_brand
  </aside>
```

You could use `data-attributes` and target the correct panel.

```js
$('a.sidepanel-toggle').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  let _this = $(this),
      tg = _this.data('panel');
  
  $('#'+tg).addClass('active');

})
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle" data-panel="extra_prod_meta">meta data</a>
  
  <aside id="extra_prod_meta" class="sidepanel">
    meta data
  </aside>

  <a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle" data-panel="extra_prod_brand">Brand</a>

  <aside id="extra_prod_brand" class="sidepanel">
    meta data
  </aside>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm much closer now :) I can open each panel, but I can't close them. As I load an overlay ontop of the body, that will make the first link inactive. I have added a second toggle link inside the aside panel <a href="#" class="sidepanel-toggle" data-panel="extra_prod_meta">X</a> but when I click that, it is closing the overlay bu not the actual panel...

Edit: I had to change addClass to toggleClass. Worked Like a charm <3. Now I just need to figure out how I can active the function/toggle from the overlay as well

Comment: Just include a button that triggers your ```toggleFunction``` and it should work.

Comment: I have included what I believe is what you are after. Please check.